# Windows phone emulator could not render simple multi-page app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm developing an application using Phonegap & jQuery Mobile.

Android version is working perfectly. But now, I'm trying to test it on the Windows Phone.

For some reason, Windows phone emulator included in the latest Visual Studio express could not render simple multi-page app.

Anyone have some pointers on how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Windows Phone 8 ? or 7?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery mobile works fine with WP7/7.5, try this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2012/04/26/more-news-from-ms-open-tech-announcing-the-open-source-metro-style-theme.aspx

and this:

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/JQueryMobile_for_Windows_Phone